# IOS Adding subview from other class programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, addsubview

i've tried to create a custom view which works like a bottom bar and it worked

Right now this function is required on multiple classes, so i try writing it into a new class and import it which likes:

```
//BottomBarLauncher.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface bottomBarLauncher : UIViewController
-(void)launchBottomBar;
@end
```

And implement it as :

```
//BottomBarLauncher.m
-(void) launchBottomBar{
    for (UIView *subView in [topView subviews]) {
        [subView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    UIView *btnBarView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,     self.view.frame.size.height - 53.3, 320, 53.3)];
    btnBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:btnBarView];
}
```

Now here's the problem, while i try implement it on a new view like follows:

```
//NewView.m
#import "BottomBarProtocol.h"

@interface NewView()
{
    BottomBarLauncher *btnBar;
}
@end
//blahblahblah

[btnBar launchBottomBar];
```

and nothing happens, i think the problem was with

```
[self.view addSubview:btnBarView];
```

but i have no idea how to select the current view as target which i can add subview onto.

Comment: Does NewView has BottomBarLauncher's view as its subview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a suggestion, looking at your requirements/code I think you want to create custom view. For creating a custom view, create a class which inherits from `UIView` rather than creating a `UIViewController`.

Now moving to the code, your `btnBar` is a `UIViewController` which has its own view `self.view` so when you call this `[btnBar launchBottomBar]` internally you are adding the bottom bar on `self.view` that is your `btnBar` controllers view and not on `NewView` controllers `view`. Hope you understand what I am pointing out.

Here you are missing out few calls,

```
btnBar.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,self.view.bounds.size.height-40,self.view.bounds.size.width,40); // Add suitable frame.

//This call will add the btnBar's view as subview onto your current view controller's view.
[self.view addSubView:btnBar.view];
```

This is not correct/recommended way and you can face serious challenges regarding memory leaks. To avoid those mistakes, as I suggested, create a custom `UIView` instead. Take a look around on how to create custom views.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Did you mean, i should try converting whole classes of BottomBarLauncher into a UIView, and add it as subview in class NewView?

Comment: Yes, is there any need for you to create a `UIViewController`?

Comment: I think UIView was what i needed, the new method works perfectly, instead i have to draw the frame each time before it launches.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the `UIView` form `launchBottomBar` method and add as a `subView` in your current `ViewController` class

Answer (score 0):

Make custom class and delegate and add that  view in window and set its frame so that it is not visible and set its frame and slide from  bottom when needed so you can use it in all view controller.
Thanks.